# OnActionResult method is not called in Android

Tags: android

I want to choose images from the Gallery. Please check the following code.

```
public class Camera extends Activity {


     private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
     private String selectedImagePath;
     WebView localview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void ChoosePhoto(WebView webview)
    {
                localview=webview;
            Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE); 
    }   

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
            {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                try {
                    FileInputStream fileis=new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
                    BufferedInputStream bufferedstream=new BufferedInputStream(fileis);
                    byte[] bMapArray= new byte[bufferedstream.available()];
                    bufferedstream.read(bMapArray);
                    localview.loadUrl("javascript:ReceivePhoto(\""+bMapArray+"\")");
                    if (fileis != null) 
                    {
                        fileis.close();
                    }
                    if (bufferedstream != null) 
                    {
                        bufferedstream.close();
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {                   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

}
```

And included the activity in Manifest file. But after choosing the image, **OnActivityResult is not called.**

Can anyone please help me???

Comment: where you are calling `ChoosePhoto` method?

Comment: While clicking on the button in html page, request is passed through one java class to this Camera class.

Comment: try after adding `intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);`

Comment: I have tried this also... no use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this.

Your Camera class:

```
public class Camera {

private Activity mParentActivity;
private OnPhotoChosenListener mPhotoChosenListener;

    // Declare an Iterface for comunicating with Activity
    interface OnPhotoChosenListener{
        public void onPhotoChosen();
    }


public Camera(Activity parentActivity) {
    mParentActivity = parentActivity;
}

public void ChoosePhoto(WebView webview)
{
    mPhotoChosenListener.onPhotoChosen();
}
```

Your Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnPhotoChosenListener{

Camera myCamera;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private String selectedImagePath;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myCamera = new Camera(this);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
        {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            try {
                FileInputStream fileis=new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
                BufferedInputStream bufferedstream=new BufferedInputStream(fileis);
                byte[] bMapArray= new byte[bufferedstream.available()];
                bufferedstream.read(bMapArray);
                localview.loadUrl("javascript:ReceivePhoto(\""+bMapArray+"\")");
                if (fileis != null) 
                {
                    fileis.close();
                }
                if (bufferedstream != null) 
                {
                    bufferedstream.close();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                 
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {                   
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onPhotoChosen(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, Comun.GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST);
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

The only thing that rest is how to call

> ChooseFoto(Webview webview)

method. This is the part i don't undestand well how to do it.
Maybe you found the solution.

**EDIT:** Code added for implementing an Interface.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your code. I have changed as you said. But i'm getting an error in "mParentActivity.methodToLaunchGalleryActivity();" see, mParetntActivity is Activity, then how can we all MyActivity method named methodToLaunchGalleryActivity(). Please once again check the code for me.

Comment: The method methodToLaunchGalleryActivity() is undefined for the type Activity. Add cast to mParentActivity.

Comment: @Ponmalar. Look at the code again. I use an Interface for comunicating the class and the Activity. Try again with this code and tell me the results.

Comment: I got an error in the line "super.onAttach(activity);" as "The method onAttach(Activity) is undefined for the type Object" and also in the line "public void onAttach(Activity activity)" as "The method onAttach(Activity) of type Camera must override a superclass method"

Comment: Thank you so much for your code... that's working too good. what i missed na, To start the new activity i forgot to call like this "Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Camera.class);  startActivity(myIntent);"

Answer (score 1):

This is what i do for picking the images from the Gallery:

Activity launch:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, Comun.GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST);
```

Capture activity result:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        mUriImagen = data.getData();

             // Do something

    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Innecesary code removed.

Comment: Can you precise what the `Comun.GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST` is?

Comment: It is just an integer for knowing form what is the origin of the Activity finished. I start the activity for the Galleric Picture Request and the Camera Picture Request.

Comment: This is working in the starting page with Actitvity, if the request is passed from one java class to another, not called

Comment: @Ponmalar, the OnActionResult is call in the same Activity from where the Gallery Pick Activity is started. Maybe you could add some code of the class where you want to pass the info.

Comment: you meant that startActivityForResult(intent, Comun.GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST); and OnActivityResult should be in same page right?

Comment: please have look on my code, both in the same class. Just I want to clarify my requirement. First page is activity page with the name "MyApplicationActivity". In that i have loaded the index.html page. then it(html) has one button to choose the picture from gallery. while clicking on the button, request is sending to CommonProcess.java class through CommonJs file. In CommonProcess.java class i have called Camera.ChoosePhoto(this.webview)."startActivityForResult" is not found in this class, so i have extended the Activity. and included in the Manifest file. Clear now?

Comment: I'm sorry but no more ideas come to my head. If ChoosePhoto method is called and the Activity for pick a photo is started, onActivityResult must be called after have picked the photo. Who calls ChoosePhoto?

Comment: User can call ChoosePhoto method. If I'm giving this code in main activity then it is working. please give some codes to access camera application with access from one java class. see this Camera class is not a activity class, just i extended.